# SSL VPN - Disable

Tags: ssl, vpn

Is there anyway to disable/stop SSL VPN on a firewall without doing SSL inspection?

My firewall is capable of doing this with inspection but I need this done without due to regulations.

Comment: you might want to tell us what firewall you're using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no completely reliable way to restrict tunneling via SSL while allowing unrestricted SSL access to any site.  Even with packet inspection it's not 100% reliable.

- If you want to prevent tunneling to a specific site (eg a specific VPN) you could block connection to that site.
- There are blocklists of proxies and VPNs, that may prevent tunneling to any established, known services, but wouldn't stop someone setting up "just a server somewhere".
- You could proxy HTTPS but that involves breaking end-to-end security for clients and installing your own CA certificate on all client machines, and if regulations prevent inspection then they'll almost certainly prevent that kind of security/privacy violation.

Comment: Thanks ... Those lists I would assume you need to subscribe to? Any you had good luck with?